# c and valgrind - why no memory leak when using malloc without free

Tags: c, valgrind

running `valgrind` I get that everything is OK - `total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,028 bytes allocated`. Why I don't need to free the `temp` on the function `bubbleSort` as well?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int array_size) {
    int i, j;
    int *temp;
    for (i = (array_size - 1); i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (numbers[j - 1] > numbers[j]) {
                temp = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int *));
                *temp = numbers[j - 1];
                numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = *temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **arr = argv + 1;
    int i, n = argc - 1;

    int *numbers = (int *) calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    printf("Original array:");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf(" %s", arr[i]);
        numbers[i] = atoi(arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    bubbleSort(numbers, n);

    printf("Sorted array:");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf(" %d", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free(numbers);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What arguments do you pass to your program?

Comment: In particular, if the array is already sorted, no malloc will be done.

Comment: By the way, you have a bug at `temp = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int *));`: should be `sizeof(int)`.  Of course, using `malloc` for this is a bit silly anyhow.

Comment: You definitely have a leak, though, and you should certainly be freeing `temp` regardless.  When I run this with arguments `5 4 3 2 1`, valgrind reports `12 allocs, 2 frees` as expected.

Comment: I run `valgrind --leak-check=full ./count-words 4321`

Comment: got it. only entered 1 number so no sort needed. thanks!